# PouchDB.query() never has the callback called back

Tags: pouchdb

We are testing PouchDB , starts ok, syncs ok , db.allDocs() works ok, but :

db.query(map, {}, function(err, data) {...});

never has the callback function called. Neither with an error, neither with data ... tested in chrome 35.0.1916.153 m...

Surprisingly , when the database is empty (Not Synced) the callback gets called with of course 0 rows returned

Any idea why ?
 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data in your database, then a temporary in-memory query (which is what you're using) may take a long time to run.

If you really want to do an in-memory query that reads in every doc in the database, just use `allDocs()` and forget that `query()` exists. Otherwise use persisted map/reduce.  Details [here](http://pouchdb.com/2014/05/01/secondary-indexes-have-landed-in-pouchdb.html).

Comment: The database is very small ! we have only 130 documents inside .. and we also tested with persisted map/reduce synced form the CouchDB server.

Comment: Ok , solved.. The problem was caused by an incorrect map function not testing if a given field was undefined or not before testing it. This occurred for only some documents, but as it was causing a blind Js exception causing the whole process to stop, we did not see it.  FYI,  in CouchDB this map function is working perfectly.